# Copying files based on partial names in a file

Tags: bash, file-copy

I have millions of xml files in a folder.  The name of the files follow a specific pattern:

```
ABC_20190101011030931_6049414.xml
```

In this I am interested only in the last set of digits before xml `6049414`.  I have a list of around 8000 such numbers in a text file.  The details in the text file is as follows - a number in a line:

```
104638
222885
108880071
```

I am using the following code to move the files from the folder that matches the number given in the text file:

```
#folder where the xml files are stored  
cd /home/iris/filesToExtract  
SECONDS=0

#This line reads each number in the hdpvr.txt file and if a match is found moves that file to another folder called xmlfiles.  
nn=($(cat /home/iris/hdpvr.txt));for x in "${nn[@]}";do ls *.xml| grep "$x"| xargs -I '{}' cp {} /home/iris/xmlfiles;done  

#this line deletes all the other xml files from filesToExtract folder
find . -name "*.xml" -delete  
echo $SECONDS
```

I am facing two issues. 1 Some of the files are not getting moved despite there is a match and 2. Even if the match is found in the middle part of the file name for example

```
from this ABC_20190101011030931_6049414.xml -> this 20190101011030931
```

if a match is found it still moves....how can I get the exact matches and move the files.

Comment: the numbers in your text file are only used to match the _XXXXX.xml in your xml filenames ?

Comment: @darxmurf yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this make the job ?

```
pushd /home/iris/filesToExtract
for i in $(</home/iris/hdpvr.txt); do find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*_$i.xml" -print0 | xargs -r -0 -i mv "{}" /home/iris/xmlfiles; done
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xml" -delete  
popd
```

- pushd will move you in the specified directory
- for+find line will get the ID from your text file, find files ending like _ID.xml and move them in the /home/iris/xmlfiles folder
- the last find like will delete the non moved files but only in this folder and not sub ones
- popd will put you back in your original directory

You can also do it the brutal way with mv but it will throw errors if a file is not found

```
pushd /home/iris/filesToExtract
for i in $(</home/iris/hdpvr.txt); do mv "*_$i.xml" /home/iris/xmlfiles; done
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xml" -delete  
popd
```

Comment: I kicked out your SECONDS variable as you did not use it in your example

Comment: Instead of using print0 and piping to xargs, let find do the work: `-exec mv -t $destdir {} +`

Comment: works too but I would "protect" your exec with double quotes like "{}"

Comment: `find` doesn't need the quotes: the shell removes them before launching find. And [bash doesn't care about empty braces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, thanks to [glenn jackmann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)!

```
#!/bin/bash

# folder where the xml files are stored
xmldir=/home/iris/filesToExtract

# xml backup folder
backupdir=/home/iris/xmlfiles

while read -r line; do
    mv -t "$backupdir" *_*_${line}.xml 2>/dev/null
done <"$xmldir/hdpvr.txt"
rm -i *.xml
```

Pattern `*_*_${line}.xml` is used to find the files in the directory.

Replace `rm -i *.xml` with `rm *.xml` if you want to delete the remaining xml files immediately.

Comment: Might be faster, instead of looping over the files and moving the one-by-one, to do `mv -t "$backupdir" *_*_"$i".xml`

Comment: Also, should not use `for` to read files: `while read -r i; do ... done < file.txt`

Comment: @glennjackman For this specific filename pattern a _dirty_ for-loop should do, but you're right!